# Parameter in IF condition for record selection in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports

I am creating a Crystal Report. In my report there are three parameters. Now I would like to filter data according to the parameter value. Therefore in record selection formula I have written the following formula.

```
(
    {Table_Name.Field01} = {?Field01}
)
and
(
    if HasValue({?Field02}) Then 
        { Table_Name. Field02} Like ('*'+{?Field02}+'*') 
    else true
)
and
(
    if HasValue({?Field03}) Then 
        { Table_Name. Field03} = ToNumber({?Field03}) 
    else True
);
```

The problem is not working. It’s only working if I add the third parameter in my IF condition.

```
and
(
    if HasValue({?Field03}) Then 
        { Table_Name. Field03} = ToNumber({?Field03}) 
    else True
);
```

Can anyone give me idea how to fix the problem. I am using Crystal Report 2008.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest avoiding the use of optional parameters- they tend to break things. If instead you can set default values- something like this:

Parameters; Name (default *ALL), Hair (default *ALL)

Then i also tend to avoid using if/then/else in record selection- stick to logical operators (and/or):

```
({?name} = '*ALL' or {table.name} = {?name})
and ({?hair} = '*ALL' or {table.hair} = {?hair})
```

In response to your additional question:

```
ucase({i.fnavn}) like '*' + ucase({?navn}) + '*'
or ucase({i.enavn}) like '*' + ucase({?navn}) + '*'
or ucase({i.navn}) like '*' + ucase({?navn}) + '*'
```

Comment: thanks for the help. Can you please suggest me how to convert the following sql query in to record selection formula in crystal report.                               where += " and (upper(i.fnavn) like '%" + Navn.ToString().ToUpper() + "%'" + " or upper(i.enavn) like '" + Navn.ToString().ToUpper() + "%'" + " or upper(i.navn) like '" + Navn.ToString().ToUpper() + "%') ";